# Query not working with ENUM field in Oracle NoSQL Database

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

I encountered issues with the execution of a select query with WHERE clause on ENUM field

Here's a sample query which is not working:

```
kv-> execute "select * from  Table1_TBL where col1 < 100 and col1 >10 and Table1Summaries.values($value.col2 = 'VAL1')"
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, in comparisons enum columns behave like strings. So if "col2" is a column of table "Table1_TBL" that is declared as an enum, the query should be the following:

select * from  Table1_TBL where col1 < 100 and col1 >10 and col2 = 'VAL1'.